# How to extract file name from file path name?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I need to move all files from source folder to destination folder. How can I easily extract file name from file path name?

```
string newPath = "C:\\NewPath";

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_configSection.ImportFilePath);
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
  // extract file name and add new path 
  File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try the following:

```
string newPathForFile = Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

Comment: Thanks, I love this site)) 1 min to get the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Got nothing better to do anyway (you know: work).

Comment: lot of people to see your problem :) , Collective Intelligence

Comment: I used `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`. +1

Answer (score 48):

```
Path.GetFileName(filePath)
```

Answer (score 10):

use DirectoryInfo and Fileinfo instead of File and Directory, they present more advanced features.

```
DirectoryInfo di = 
    new DirectoryInfo("Path");
FileInfo[] files = 
    di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo f in files)
    f.MoveTo("newPath");
```

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try the FileInfo.MoveTo method (code example at the following link):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
string newPath = "C:\\NewPath"; 
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_configSection.ImportFilePath);  
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)  
{  
   string newFilePath = Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetFileName(filePath);
   File.Move(filePath, newFilePath);
}
```