# How to save filename only to the gridview but I need path while downloading the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, file-upload, datagridview

I got finally, how to download the file using the path. But I was wondering how can I keep the file name only on the grid view. While I need the full path for downloading.

On debugging I came to see that I cannot keep file name only on file upload. Since it is carried to the downloading section. **If I keep file name, then file name is carried to the downloading part and the file is not downloaded.**

Can anyone help me

Codes

```
 private void UploadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            //Set File dialog properties
            fileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            fileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
            fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
            fileDialog.Title = "Select a file";
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strfilename = fileDialog.FileName;
                cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = strfilename;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Download Attachment from the provided DataGridViewCell
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dgvCell"></param>
    private void DownloadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        string fileName = Convert.ToString(dgvCell.Value);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {

            byte[] objData;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;

            //show save as dialog
            using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                //Set Save dialog properties
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExtension + ")|*" + fileExtension;
                saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File as";
                saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;

                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string s = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    objData = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, objData);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But if i get you right. Why don't you use use a column for the name and a hidden/0 width column for the file path. Its a  grid and therefore you may have many columns. Plus i am thinking the code below should return the full path , unless you trim and can't see where you trim .

```
            string strfilename = fileDialog.FileName;
```

To get the file name only you can use the Path

```
   string filenameOnly= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strfilename);
```

The above should return your file name only you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) for better understanding.

Add another column and set the width to 0 . Example below

```
  DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
    column.Width = 0;
cncInfoDataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

Save your file path in the new column width a 0 width and retrieve during download.

A similar question was asked here. 
[How to extract file name from file path name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986503/how-to-extract-file-name-from-file-path-name)

Comment: I am not getting i tried the way you said. Its showing the same path in the new column too. `string strfilename = fileDialog.FileName;
                  
                    cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = strfilename;
                    string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strfilename);
                    //filenameOnly = string.Empty;
                    this.cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = filenameOnly;/// place where the path of drawing is holded`

Comment: Put a break point at string `filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strfilename);` and see the value of filenameonly. filenameonly will return the file name only n doubt abt that. (e. file.doc, file.exe, file.xls etc). Put a break point and tell us what the value is pls.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, byte[]> _myAttachments;
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.
            //make sure user select only single cell
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                UploadAttachment(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0]);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.
        //make sure user select only single cell
        //and the cell have a value in it
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 1 && dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value != null)
        {
            DownloadAttachment(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0]);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.
        //make sure user select only single cell
        //and the cell have a value in it
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 1 && dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value != null)
        {
            DownloadAttachment(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0]);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    private void UploadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            //Set File dialog properties
            fileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            fileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
            fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
            fileDialog.Title = "Select a file";
            fileDialog.Multiselect = false;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName);
                byte[] binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);
                dataGridView1.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = fileInfo.Name;

                if (_myAttachments.ContainsKey(dgvCell.RowIndex))
                    _myAttachments[dgvCell.RowIndex] = binaryData;
                else
                    _myAttachments.Add(dgvCell.RowIndex, binaryData);
            }
        }
    }
    private void DownloadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        string fileName = Convert.ToString(dgvCell.Value);

        //Return if the cell is empty
        if (fileName == string.Empty)
            return;

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
        string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;

        byte[] byteData = null;

        //show save as dialog
        using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            //Set Save dialog properties
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExtension + ")|*" + fileExtension;
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File as";
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                byteData = _myAttachments[dgvCell.RowIndex];
                File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, byteData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should add some explanation why and how this code solves the asker's question. Just posting only code is considered low quality here.